# "Ping" causing "command not found" in Cygwin part-time

Tags: cygwin, windows-8.1, ping

If I launch Cygwin using the Start Menu shortcut it created, I have access to *ping* and *inetutils*. However, if I launch Cygwin directly from *C:\Cygwin64\Bin\mintty.exe* then there's no *ping* to be had; not the "socket operation not permitted message" you'd get from a non-admin launch, I get the one you'd receive if *ping* wasn't installed at all.

Am I overlooking something? The only switch in the shortcut is "*-i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico*", and manually adding that to a shortcut I create myself doesn't rectify the situation. This is occurring on Windows 8.1 Pro in an admin account.

Comment: There is no `ping` in cygwin. When it does work, what does `type ping` give you?

Comment: ..huh? There most definitely IS a ping package you can install through Cygwin setup. It's also in the list of available packages here: https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=ping&arch=x86_64

Comment: My bad. It requires privilege elevation, see this [recent answer](https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin/2015-09/msg00049.html) and [this](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2009-12/msg00164.html) older one from Corinna Vinschen herself. IIRC there was a post that recommended using the windows version too. Perhaps you are running in one of the two cases as administrator?

Comment: If I run it without admin I get the "socket operation not permitted" message which results from ping trying to run without proper privileges. My problem is that Cygwin is behaving as if the packages *aren't even installed* when launched from the executable directly.

Comment: What is the path when it does not work?

Comment: Try  `C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -e /bin/bash --login` or similar as applicable in your setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `mintty` without arguments will run your `$SHELL` but not as login shell, which won't set `PATH` etc.

From mintty documentation [synopsis](http://mintty.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1065/trunk/docs/mintty.1.html#1) and [invocation](http://mintty.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1065/trunk/docs/mintty.1.html#3):

> mintty [OPTION]... [ - | PROGRAM [ARG]... ]  [...]
>
> If a program name
>   is supplied on the command line, this is executed with any additional
>   arguments given. Otherwise, mintty looks for a shell to execute in the
>   SHELL environment variable. If that is not set, it reads the user’s
>   default shell setting from /etc/passwd. As a last resort, it falls
>   back to /bin/sh. If a single dash is specified instead of a program
>   name, the shell is invoked as a login shell.

So, the following should get you going, it worked for me.

```
c:\cygwin64\bin\mintty -
```

That is, invoke `mintty` with `-` as parameter

Comment: I saw it had "-i /pathtoicon -", but like a fool I assumed that the final '-' was erroneous and completely forgot about seeing it after making that assumption. Thanks!

Comment: I made a bunch of foolish guesses before zeroing in on the the correct solution so I guess we are even :) Can I ask how is your experience with mintty? I use xterm with tmux and wondering if using mintty has advantages over that.

Comment: Just came back to say thanks again! I clean-installed Win10 and found myself unable to pin a working shell to the taskbar. After futzing for a minute I recalled it had to do with the arguments, but couldn't remember specifically. So glad that Stack Overflow is here!